# ReactJS SSR app whole content disappears when "homepage": used in package.json

Tags: reactjs

I have a reactJS SSR app deployed into server, I am trying to use one of the page /listpage as a widget into some other website

The list page is appearing nicely in other website however some of the click actions were not working, when I debugged it I found that the issue was with serving reactjs static js chunk files which were created by react run build. The issue was with relative path /static/js/xxxx

to fix this issue, one solution is to have a full path reference, to enable that I added homepage:"" in package.json

this worked and when I checked network tab in chrome browser i could see all static js files are referred using full path.

however a strange issue occurred , the whole list widget appears and suddenly disappears , when I inspect the elements I could see nothing inside  thats where all react components suppose to be rendered.

for full code of SSR project kindly [refer](http://knowledge-cess.com/server-side-rendering-in-react-16-with-create-react-app-using-material-ui-redux-and-express-libraries/) with explanation.
however the full code is in [github](https://github.com/pilleanand/ssr-react16/tree/master/ssr-react-16)